# Can a spell that doesn't require concentration be cast twice by the same person and remain active at the same time?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

I was attempting to answer [this question about how to cast spells in a vacuum](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/133370/how-to-cast-spells-in-a-vacuum/133374#133374), when the issue of casting *mirage arcane* twice and/or the gap between castings came up.

**Can a spell that doesn't require concentration be cast twice by the same caster before the duration of the first casting ends?**

Comment: @PurpleMonkey I am attempting to answer https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/133370/how-to-cast-spells-in-a-vacuum/133374#133374 and the issue of casting mirage arcane comes up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### In most cases, yes, it can

There is no rule anywhere that would stop a wizard from casting *Mage Armor* on herself, and then casting *Mage Armor* again on someone else.

#### But not if they're cast on the same target

*Combining Magical Effects* on page 205 of the PhB says:

> The effects of the same spell cast multiple times don't combine. Instead, the most potent effect, such as the highest bonus - from those castings apply while their durations overlap.

#### Or if the spell says otherwise

For example. the *Contingency* spell says

> You can use only one contingency spell at a time. If you cast this spell again, the effect of another contingency spell on you ends.

In this case, it would not be possible for the same caster to cast it multiple times.

Comment: Given the context the asker has edited in, you may want to clarify what this means for [*mirage arcane*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/mirage-arcane) in particular.

Comment: while effects from the same source (spell) do not stack, both effects in and of themselves are still in effect, which can become relevant when it comes to durations and dispels. In the example given, the effects of Mage Armor only applies once, but it is still important to remember that the character has two castings of Mage Armor on, since they may (for a variety of reasons, including just duration) run out or disappear at different times.