# Can you use Wand of Wonder underwater?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, underwater

Because you can't speak normally while underwater, you can't cast spells with verbal components. So you also can't activate magic items that require command words. (https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/77917/37116 )

The Wand of Wonder doesn't mention a command word though:

> While holding it, you can use an action to expend 1 of its charges and choose a target within 120 feet of you. The target can be a creature, an object, or a point in space. Roll d100 and consult the following table to discover what happens.

So it should work. But what if it causes you to cast a spell with verbal components?

Comment: The underlying question seems to be: **does a spell "cast" from an item requires you to supply the (VSM) components?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Yes, because the spells require no components

DMG 141:

> Some magic items allow the user to cast a spell from the item. The spell is cast at the lowest possible spell level, doesn't expend any of the user's spell slots, and requires no components, unless the item's description says otherwise.

Since the item's description doesn't say otherwise, none of the spells cast by *Wand of Wonder* require components, verbal or otherwise.